# OSX: hard disk space different in Disk utility

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have 2 differents 'free space' digits.
And after delete something big from disk -> free space in 'About your mac' - still unchanged.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't read Russian, could you please translate that?

Comment: This question is similar to the one I posted some times ago where there were even three different HD space indications in my Mac.
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215213/different-free-space-indications-in-macintosh-hd-after-upgrading-to-el-capitan
Unfortunately, I didn't get any answer. Any help?

Comment: @mgiordi - yeap, problem was solved! I answer on your question.

Comment: @brick - different GB for availability  (59,35 GB vs 139,6 GB)